# How to add CollectionView to TableViewCell and detect when CollectionView finish loading cells to request TableViewCell height update

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I want to add a dynamic `UICollectionView` inside dynamic `UITableViewCell`, which automatically should update its height when `CollectionView` receives and prepares `contentView`.
What is a good method to achieve it?
I tried few, but code becomes a bit messy, and was hopping there is a bette way.

Is it possible to detect when `CollectionView` `contentView` finish loading, i.e. frame is updated?

Is it ok to request tableView cell height updates from collectionView `cellForItemAtIndexPath`?

*Looking for solution without storyboards and constraints.*

Answer (score 0):

```
self?.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({ () -> Void in
    self?.collectionView?.reloadData()
}, completion: { (_) -> Void in
    // Or whatever you want to do
})
```

You can perform `tableView.reloadRowAtIndexPath(:)` in completion block and pass the height from `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: Not sure why yet, but it didn't worked for me. Gave "Invalid update: invalid number of items in section 0." when tried to implement completion section. Though, there was nothing that could effect number of items, I would like to believe. Does it work for you?

Comment: are you using insertItemsAtIndexPaths or reloadData?

Comment: I used reloadData() same as you wrote in first closure.